# Does anyone know how to connect grails app to mongoDB cloud database?

Tags: mongodb, grails, mongodb-atlas

I created a database in MongoDB atlas and I want to create a Grails app that will connect to that database, and I have no idea how to do it. Here's what I tried in "application.yml" file, but it doesn't work.

```
environments:
    development:
        grails:
            mongodb:
                host: "clustertpt.nfycx.mongodb.net"
                port: 27017
                username: "x"
                password: "x"
                databaseName: "tpt"
    production:
        grails:
            mongodb:
                host: "clustertpt.nfycx.mongodb.net"
                port: 27017
                username: "x"
                password: "x"
                databaseName: "tpt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this way and it worked!

```
environments:
        development:
            grails:
                mongodb:
                    url: "mongodb+srv://x:x@clustertpt.nfycx.mongodb.net/tpt?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
        test:
            development:
                grails:
                    mongodb:
                        url: "mongodb+srv://x:x@clustertpt.nfycx.mongodb.net/tpt?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
        production:
            development:
                grails:
                    mongodb:
                        url: "mongodb+srv://x:x@clustertpt.nfycx.mongodb.net/tpt?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```